# Music Policies on Facebook: Using Copyright But Licensed Music

Tags: copyright, music

Is there any way to figure out which music is allowed on Facebook?

A year or two ago there was an announcement saying that you are now allowed to upload videos with copyrighted music on Facebook since they signed a deal with several companies.

However, there is no “YouTube Music Policies”-equivalent page on Facebook. Most sites mention that you can now use copyrighted music, but it doesn't explain whether you can use any music (which I doubt) you like. There's also a mention that Facebook will notify you once you uploaded a video that you have used a copyrighted music — by then it will be too late.

Oftentimes I edit my video around the music and I don't want to spend all my time on a video just to receive a copyright strike.

I Googled this multiple time to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whats allowed on Facebook but, to keep it safe use songs from Youtube audio library that are not copy right protected. At some songs you need to add the author and by others no. You can also use filters. Now i agree most of the songs wont fit your needs, but i have to say there are some great songs in there!

Comment: I do know the existence of free or even paid libraries out there. However, most of the songs are too simple to me to the extent that they sound cheap. Non-royalty free music generally sound better and more layered. There are some exceptions with new artists but it's difficult to cut through the noise. That's why I'm looking to use copyrighted songs if I can - especially if Facebook has already licensed it. It's just a shame that I could not seem to find a list of licensed music that I can use.

Answer (score 0):

The answer should be in Facebook's terms of service, if they don't say anything, it's allowed. If it's forbidden this can only be limited to unlicensed work, everything else would be an illegal attack to artistic freedom. If Facebook wrongly awards you a copyright strike and your business suffers damage you should go to court.

Facebook's support is too dumb to understand even the simplest problems, you can't expect to solve such a problem by discussing.

I think Facebook is only good as one of your many marketing channels, you should never rely on Facebook in any way, and it should never be the primary location where you publish anything.